# Sharepoint 2013 sp1, где взять сервисы

Tags: администрирование, sharepoint

На одной виртуалке развернул Sharepoint 2013 sp1.
Нужно развернуть два сервиса, но их "нет в наличии" в центре администрирования. 
- Managed Metadata service
- User Profile Service Application

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где их можно найти?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Эти службы недоступны в SharePoint Foundation 2013, нужно версию выше брать!

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint__cloud/2013/01/09/sharepoint-2013-onpremise-edition-comparison-chart/